# What are the mathematical consequences if $10$ is proved to be solitary?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum

Let $\sigma(x) = \sigma_{1}(x)$ denote the *sum of the divisors* of $x$, and let
$$I(x) = \dfrac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
be the *abundancy index* of $x$.

For example,
$$\sigma(10) = 1 + 2 + 5 + 10 = 18$$
so that
$$I(10) = \dfrac{\sigma(10}{10} = \dfrac{18}{10} = \dfrac{9}{5}.$$

Consider the equation
$$I(x) = I(a)$$
where $a$ is fixed.  If $x \neq a$, then $x$ is said to be a *friend* of $a$.  We will then call $x$ and $a$ as *friendly numbers*.  On the other hand, if $x = a$ whenever
$$I(x) = I(a),$$
then $a$ is called a *[solitary number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html)*.

In this paper by [Ward](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.1001), necessary conditions for the existence of a friend of $10$ is derived. It is conjectured that $10$ is in fact solitary, although a proof appears to be very difficult.

My question in the present post is as follows:

> What would be the mathematical consequences, if any, of proving that $10$ is solitary?

Comment: Further insights for the sum of divisor function $\sigma(n)$ (Andrew Feist, *Fun* with the sigma(n) function). So then we know why we have $10$ fingers, and not $12=\sigma(6)$.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reference, @DietrichBurde!  Will check that out.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, do you have a copy of Feist's paper?  I tracked down the paper's journal reference (plus URL) in [OEIS A014567](https://oeis.org/A014567), but the following link that appears therein appears to be broken:  http://www.math-cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/2003.3/feist.pdf.  Additionally, the Project Euclid page for MJMS does not have the issues for the year 2003.

Comment: Got it!  Was able to obtain a DVI copy from this link:  http://cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/2003.3/feist.dvi.

Comment: Yes, there is also [this link](http://plouffe.fr/simon/OEIS/citations/feist.pdf), which seems to work.